# Should I include all my custom exceptions in one file?

Tags: python, exception, module, directory-structure, modularization

I have a module with several files, some of which have a few custom exceptions declared. These exceptions are primarily raised in the file they are declared, but sometimes they are also raised in other files in the module. Is it best practice to just make a new file (ie `errors.py`) and put all exceptions there, or continue to keep them in there respective files?

Comment: All custom exceptions in one file seems best to me. IMHO, do what you think is best from a maintenance perspective.

Comment: This question maybe too broad for stackoverflow. Can you please ask them in the sites like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it a very good idea to do so!
It is easier to maintain refactor in case you want to add new exceptions or modify existing ones.

Just be considerate with the level of separation you introduce.
Personally, I have caught myself sometimes overdoing it with this and I have shot myself to the foot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).